# How can I combine these methods with similar functionality Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

These 2 methods do almost the same thing.
Only Post method looped through english groups and then also post in english, and postNL does that in dutch, How can I make this shorter code without losing functionality?

**This is my code**

```
message = "Hi"
messageNL = "Hoi"

def post(status, filename_tmp, filename_txt):
    tmp_file = open(filename_tmp, "w")
    with open(filename_txt) as listOfGroups:
        for group in listOfGroups:
            driver.get(group)
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                if status:
                    #try posting
                    try:
                        postClick = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span"))).click()
                        #typ message 
                        post_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div"))).send_keys(message)
                        #click on post
                        post_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div"))).click()
                        time.sleep(2)
                        #wait till posted 
                        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span")))
                        tmp_file.write(group)           
                    #continue to next url if xpath is'nt found
                    except:
                        continue
                else:
                    continue
            except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                continue 
    #delete url if xpaths not found            
    tmp_file.close()
    shutil.copyfile(filename_tmp, filename_txt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    post(True, "fbgroepen.tmp", "fbgroepen.txt") 
    post(True, "fbgroepenNL.tmp", "fbgroepenNL.txt")
```

This are my 2 methods, what should i do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it should be enough to add some attributes in the function, isn't it?

Comment: can you show a example on what you should do?

Comment: Read this pls https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here I add some variables to the post function. I don't know if this could be a solution:

```
post(status, "fbgroepen.tmp", "fbgroepen.txt")
post(status, "fbgroepenNL.tmp", "fbgroepenNL.txt")

def post(status, filename_tmp, filename_txt):
    tmp_file = open(filename_tmp, "w")
    with open(filename_txt) as listOfGroups:
        for group in listOfGroups:
            driver.get(group)
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                if status:
                    #try posting
                    try:
                        postClick = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span"))).click()
                        #typ message 
                        post_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div"))).send_keys(message)
                        #click on post
                        post_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div"))).click()
                        time.sleep(2)
                        #wait till posted 
                        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span")))
                        tmp_file.write(group)           
                    #continue to next url if xpath is'nt found
                    except:
                        continue
                else:
                    continue
            except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                continue 
    #delete url if xpaths not found            
    tmp_file.close()
    shutil.copyfile(filename_tmp, filename_txt)
```

Comment: only the two first lines gives me errors i use the following

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__":     post(True)`

Comment: which error? so if you replace post(True) with the first two lines it doeasn't work?

Comment: i updated the code in my question he doesn't recognize status in if_name_ == main

Comment: you should replace "status" with True, so:

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__":
    post(True, "fbgroepen.tmp", "fbgroepen.txt")
    post(True, "fbgroepenNL.tmp", "fbgroepenNL.txt")

Comment: it kinda works but he is ignoring the fbgroepenNL i updated my code in my question

Comment: how do you notice that he ignores the fbgroepenNL? Is there any kind of output?

Comment: i also use 2 different txt files

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily combine these 2 methods by using a parameter, like this:

```
message = "Hi"
messageNL = "Hoi"

def post(status, file_name, message):
    tmp_file = open(file_name + ".tmp", "w")
    with open(file_name + ".txt") as listOfGroups:
        for group in listOfGroups:
            driver.get(group)
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                if status:
                    #try posting
                    try:
                        postClick = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span"))).click()
                        #typ message 
                        post_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div"))).send_keys(message)
                        #click on post
                        post_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div"))).click()
                        time.sleep(2)
                        #wait till posted 
                        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span")))
                        tmp_file.write(group)           
                    #continue to next url if xpath is'nt found
                    except:
                        continue
                else:
                    continue
            except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                continue 
    #delete url if xpaths not found            
    tmp_file.close()
    shutil.copyfile(file_name + ".tmp", file_name + ".txt")
```

Now you can call this method with appropriate parameters:

```
post(status, "fbgroepen", message)
```

or

```
post(status, "fbgroepenNL", messageNL)
```

So as you involve this it would be something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    post(True, "fbgroepen", "Hi")
    post(True, "fbgroepenNL", "Hoi")
```

Comment: how can i call this methods correctly then i used this in my old code `if __name__ == "__main__":
    post(True)`

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__":
    post(status, "fbgroepen", "Hi")`

Comment: status isnt defined there

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__":     post(True, "fbgroepen", "Hi")`

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" please give details: what exception, on what code line? Otherwise the answer is "if so you should fix something"

Comment: the for loop stops after the first post = true i also edited the code in my question

Comment: I didn't actually change your original code.

Comment: he is only doing the first post true part

Comment: And what you want it to do?

Comment: the posting in dutch and english in the same method

Comment: it works only for fbgroepen but he isnt doing the fbgroepenNL

Comment: but i use 2 txt files btw

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm expecting some basic programming knowledge and experience from person asking a programming question.  Can't see that here, sorry.

Comment: what do i need to do